# What is the word for 'addition before something'

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to come up with a word meaning 'addition (before something)' in the sense:
His title was 'holiness' but now it must be expressed with the ?something? 'supreme' (such that the title is now 'supreme holiness'). I want it to be clear that 'supreme' has to be added before the term 'holiness'.
I thought perhaps 'superaddition', but that's somewhat different.

Comment: I would say it was an "honorific", or, if necessary, an "honorific adjective".

Comment: *epithet*, *qualifier*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There might be a technical word that is specific for titles, but the word that seems to come most naturally is:

> it must be ***prefixed*** with 'supreme'

Or:

> it must be expressed [adorned?] with the 'supreme' *prefix*

The words *prepended* and *adjoined* also come to mind, but the first is mostly used in computer science, and the second connotes affixing more than prefixing.

Comment: +1 for “prefix” as a noun (which fits the OP’s example as given better than a verb) and also for suggesting “adorned” to emphasize that this is an addition to the original title/honorific prefix.  I would, however, maintain the OP’s word order (“the ?something? ‘supreme’ ”=“the prefix ‘supreme’ ”) to avoid the slight ambiguity that arises in my mind when the order is reversed (even with the quotation marks, “the ‘supreme’ prefix” could perhaps beg the question, “well what exactly is the ‘supreme’ prefix?”), but it’s probably just me.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest '**prepend**'.

> His title 'Holiness' must be **prepended** with 'Supreme' now.

Answer (score 0):

You could say

> Instead of 'holiness' he must be called 'supreme holiness'.

This leaves no room for misunderstanding. The fact that 'supreme' must come before 'holiness' is clear from the concrete term 'supreme holiness' where 'supreme' does indeed appear before 'holiness'